# What are the meanings of the hash keys when calling ObjectSpace.count_objects?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.9 (YARV) you can get a count of all currently allocated objects like so:

```
ObjectSpace.count_objects
```

which returns a hash like

```
{:TOTAL=>1226560, :FREE=>244204, :T_OBJECT=>26141, :T_CLASS=>9819, :T_MODULE=>1420, :T_FLOAT=>287,
 :T_STRING=>260476, :T_REGEXP=>4081, :T_ARRAY=>72269, :T_HASH=>14923, :T_STRUCT=>4601, :T_BIGNUM=>7,
 :T_FILE=>16, :T_DATA=>54553, :T_MATCH=>5, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_RATIONAL=>15, :T_NODE=>524818, 
 :T_ICLASS=>8924}
```

What is the meaning of these hash keys?  Some like T_STRING and T_FILE are obvious.  I'm particularly curious about :FREE, :T_ICLASS, :T_DATA, and :T_NODE.

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess: I assume `:T_ICLASS` counts *include classes* and `:T_NODE` could maybe stand for *AST nodes*.

Here's a full list (unfortunately without comments):

```
#define T_NONE   RUBY_T_NONE
#define T_NIL    RUBY_T_NIL
#define T_OBJECT RUBY_T_OBJECT
#define T_CLASS  RUBY_T_CLASS
#define T_ICLASS RUBY_T_ICLASS
#define T_MODULE RUBY_T_MODULE
#define T_FLOAT  RUBY_T_FLOAT
#define T_STRING RUBY_T_STRING
#define T_REGEXP RUBY_T_REGEXP
#define T_ARRAY  RUBY_T_ARRAY
#define T_HASH   RUBY_T_HASH
#define T_STRUCT RUBY_T_STRUCT
#define T_BIGNUM RUBY_T_BIGNUM
#define T_FILE   RUBY_T_FILE
#define T_FIXNUM RUBY_T_FIXNUM
#define T_TRUE   RUBY_T_TRUE
#define T_FALSE  RUBY_T_FALSE
#define T_DATA   RUBY_T_DATA
#define T_MATCH  RUBY_T_MATCH
#define T_SYMBOL RUBY_T_SYMBOL
#define T_RATIONAL RUBY_T_RATIONAL
#define T_COMPLEX RUBY_T_COMPLEX
#define T_UNDEF  RUBY_T_UNDEF
#define T_NODE   RUBY_T_NODE
#define T_ZOMBIE RUBY_T_ZOMBIE
#define T_MASK   RUBY_T_MASK
```

The `RUBY_T_xyz` enum is defined like this:

```
enum ruby_value_type {
    RUBY_T_NONE   = 0x00,

    RUBY_T_OBJECT = 0x01,
    RUBY_T_CLASS  = 0x02,
    RUBY_T_MODULE = 0x03,
    RUBY_T_FLOAT  = 0x04,
    RUBY_T_STRING = 0x05,
    RUBY_T_REGEXP = 0x06,
    RUBY_T_ARRAY  = 0x07,
    RUBY_T_HASH   = 0x08,
    RUBY_T_STRUCT = 0x09,
    RUBY_T_BIGNUM = 0x0a,
    RUBY_T_FILE   = 0x0b,
    RUBY_T_DATA   = 0x0c,
    RUBY_T_MATCH  = 0x0d,
    RUBY_T_COMPLEX  = 0x0e,
    RUBY_T_RATIONAL = 0x0f,

    RUBY_T_NIL    = 0x11,
    RUBY_T_TRUE   = 0x12,
    RUBY_T_FALSE  = 0x13,
    RUBY_T_SYMBOL = 0x14,
    RUBY_T_FIXNUM = 0x15,

    RUBY_T_UNDEF  = 0x1b,
    RUBY_T_NODE   = 0x1c,
    RUBY_T_ICLASS = 0x1d,
    RUBY_T_ZOMBIE = 0x1e,

    RUBY_T_MASK   = 0x1f
};
```

I think most of those are rather obvious. The only ones I can't figure out are `T_DATA` (see @banister's comment), `T_ZOMBIE` and `T_MASK`.

BTW: Note that these are *not* part of Ruby 1.9. They are part of YARV. They might be totally different on other implementations of Ruby 1.9 or even not exist *at all*. The documentation clearly states:

> The contents of the returned hash is implementation defined. It may be changed in future.

In fact, it isn't even guaranteed that the method itself exists:

> This method is not expected to work except C Ruby.

(By which the author presumably means that the method is only guaranteed to work on MRI and YARV.)

Comment: and `:T_DATA` is a data wrapped struct

Answer (score 1):

You can get more information about the `T_DATA` category by calling `ObjectSpace.count_tdata_objects` (described [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html)).

I believe that these are native objects controlled by the VM.  Sometimes native extensions can allocate them, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The types are described in the file [`doc/extension.doc`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/extension.rdoc) in Ruby source code:

```
T_NIL       :: nil
T_OBJECT    :: ordinary object
T_CLASS     :: class
T_MODULE    :: module
T_FLOAT     :: floating point number
T_STRING    :: string
T_REGEXP    :: regular expression
T_ARRAY     :: array
T_HASH      :: associative array
T_STRUCT    :: (Ruby) structure
T_BIGNUM    :: multi precision integer
T_FIXNUM    :: Fixnum(31bit or 63bit integer)
T_COMPLEX   :: complex number
T_RATIONAL  :: rational number
T_FILE      :: IO
T_TRUE      :: true
T_FALSE     :: false
T_DATA      :: data
T_SYMBOL    :: symbol
```

In addition, there are several other types used internally:

```
T_ICLASS    :: included module
T_MATCH     :: MatchData object
T_UNDEF     :: undefined
T_NODE      :: syntax tree node
T_ZOMBIE    :: object awaiting finalization
```