# What is the meaning of :FREE in ObjectSpace.count_objects on ruby MRI

Tags: ruby

I would like to know what the count associated with the key `:FREE` returned from `ObjectSpace.count_object`. The documentation says this hash is implementation-specific, and so my question refers specifically to MRI ruby 2.1.

There have been at least two questions about this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789929/on-ruby-1-9-what-are-the-meanings-of-the-hash-keys-when-calling-objectspace-cou) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892125/whats-the-meaning-of-each-hash-value-in-objectspace-count-objects)), but no answers regarding `:FREE`.

Any ideas?

In some cases, the free count is much higher than the number of objects accessible through `ObjectSpace.each_object` and thus I don't seem to have any information about them. Are they taking up memory. In my program the `:FREE` count is high even after running garbage collection.

Comment: As I recall, MRI's GC doesn't actually free allocated objects when it cleans up. Instead it collects the unused object in a linked list. These objects are recycled into new objects as needed. This reduces the amount of actual allocation/freeing that needs to be done. I would guess that `:FREE` is the size of this linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find the meaning of `:FREE` straight from the implementation itself (from [gc.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/gc.c#L3124) )

```
*  The keys starting with +:T_+ means live objects.
*  For example, +:T_ARRAY+ is the number of arrays.
*  +:FREE+ means object slots which is not used now.
*  +:TOTAL+ means sum of above.
```

Then we can take a look at the tests for it (from [test_gc.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/test/ruby/test_gc.rb#L92)) :

```
assert_equal(count[:TOTAL]-count[:FREE], stat[:heap_live_slots])
assert_equal(count[:FREE], stat[:heap_free_slots])
```

And finally, we can double check there's no funny business going on with:
`GC.stat[:heap_free_slot] == ObjectSpace.count_objects[:FREE]`

`irb(main):001:0> GC.stat[:heap_free_slot] == ObjectSpace.count_objects[:FREE]
=> true`

So, `:FREE` indicates the number of allocated slots on the heap that haven't been used.